# AWS Lambda having Intermittent 502 or 504 (Endpoint request timed out) error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I encountered some weird intermittent '502' & '504' issue in my AWS API

Description/Flow:

1. Someone call my "pet" API.
2. "pet" API will trigger "pet" lambda function that will call another API, which is "petDetails".
3. "petDetails" API will trigger a "petDetails" lambda function.
4. "petDetails" lambda function timeout with unknown reason.

## petDetails Lambda Function

```
console.log("Lambda-LibraryLoading");

const Promise = require("bluebird");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

console.log("Lambda-LibraryLoaded");


exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {

    console.log("Lambda-FunctionStart");

    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

## petDetails logs in AWS Cloudwatch

```
START RequestId: b0d14e3b-3f2b-4094-8b6c-5bec1e034f35 Version: $LATEST

END RequestId: b0d14e3b-3f2b-4094-8b6c-5bec1e034f35

REPORT RequestId: b0d14e3b-3f2b-4094-8b6c-5bec1e034f35  Duration: 30030.19 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB  Max Memory Used: 88 MB
```

Comment: Enable to AWS X-ray, it help us to trace and see which part/component/services cause error or throttled.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. How do you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Default timeout of lambda function is 3sec, you can increase it in aws console. 
This problem of taking too much time on first execution is called [cold start](https://hackernoon.com/cold-starts-in-aws-lambda-f9e3432adbf0).

you can avoid 500s by

1. Not having too many sequential calls so that request time is less
2. increasing the timeout of lambda function
3. keeping the lambda function alive by using health checks.

All these are workaround only and you response times will still be high and you should revisit your design.

Comment: The default timeout of lambda is 6s. 30s is for API Gateway.